# QGridLayout Widgets Set Equal Size

Tags: c++, qt, qlayout, qgridlayout

.h file:

```
QChartView *chrtViewArr[5];
QGridLayout *graphLayout;
QFrame *graphFrame;
```

.cpp file:

```
{
...
this->graphLayout = new QGridLayout(this->graphFrame);

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        this->graphLayout->addWidget(this->chrtViewArr[i],i,0);
    }

this->graphFrame->setLayout(this->graphLayout);

for(int i=0;i<machine_count;i++){
        this->InsertIntoByteArray(this->chrtViewArr[i]);
    }
...
widget.show();
}

void GraphDialog::InsertIntoByteArray(QChartView *chartView){
    this->pixmap = chartView->grab();
    QBuffer buffer(&this->byteArray);
    buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    this->pixmap.save(&buffer,"JPG");
}
```

When I run this code the placement of widgets are like this:[image: widget placement]

How can I set the widget height and width equal? I tried to use QVBoxLayout istead of QGridLayout but nothing has changed. When I command out InsertIntoByteArray() function problem fixed but I need to use that function to save graphs. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the chart widgets' sizePolicy to ignore the sizeHint

Comment: That worked. this->chrtViewArr[i]->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored,QSizePolicy::Ignored);